# Paginated, randomized search result, without clumping

Tags: ruby-on-rails, algorithm, sorting, e-commerce

For our RoR-based e-commerce site, we are showing a paginated search result of products. Even when randomized, this list frequently has several products of the same brand clumped together. We want a search result that is "de-clumped" such that products of the same brand don't appear near one another.

For example, if I have thousands of products that belong to 50 brands and I'm showing fewer than 50 products on the page, it shouldn't show more than one product per brand on that page (or preferably some configurable maximum). I would have to maintain a "seed" value of some sort to pass in as the user advances from page to page so that I can recreate the search order.

What algorithm or strategy can I use to accomplish this de-clumped/randomized result?

Comment: Can you first pick a brand (with probability equal to the number of products of that brand divided by the total number of products) and then pick a random product of that brand? If you keep track of the products of the previous pages, you don't need a seed.

Comment: Is there some other sorting criteria?  Does this need to somehow work with a relevance, newest, highest rated, etc sorting?  If so what happens when The first ten items should all be from one superior vendor?

Comment: @Speed8ump - That's a good question, but at this time, we're not using a vendor rating of any sort, and an option search keyword is the only relevance-based aspect of the search filters we use (everything else is boolean in nature, it either matches a condition or doesn't). Currently the sorting is based on entry date into the system which causes a lot of clumping. Doing a pure randomized result obviously reduces the clumping, but it still occurrs. Looking through a lot of major retailers, their search results tend to not be clumped by brand at all. That's what we're going for.

Answer (score 2):

I could describe the strategy that virtocommerce propose, it woroks on catalog level. Here is possible to group similar "variations" to "products". Then variations could be marked as not visible during search or/and in the e-store main catalog when products are visible and could inherit some "variations" keywords to be searchable. The variations are still purchasable but only from the product page.